# Angularjs Directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a directive and am running into some problems with the scope object. In creating a plunkr to display what is happening I noticed that I'm close, but not quite sure what I'm misunderstanding.

If i have a directive that looks like this:

```
angular.module('inputExample', [])
       .directive('test',
       function() { 
         return{
         restrict: 'E',
         link: function(scope){
           scope.testInput = 1;
           scope.$watch(
             'testInput',
             function(newTestInput){
               console.log(newTestInput);
             },
             false);
         }
         }
       });
```

And utilize the directive in the view like this:

```
  <test>
    <input data-ng-model="testInput" />
    <div>
      {{testInput}}
    </div>
```

the div seems to be updated correctly and there is a message logged to the console as I would expect.

If I create the directive like this though:

```
angular.module('inputExample', [])
          .directive('example',
           function() { 
             return{
            scope: {
              'settings': '@'
            },
             restrict: 'E',
             link: function(scope){
               scope.exampleInput = 1;
               scope.$watch(
                 'exampleInput',
                 function(newTestInput){
                   console.log(newTestInput);
                 },
                 false);
             }
             }
           });
  </test>
```

and use it in a view like this:

```
  <example>
    <input data-ng-model="exampleInput" />
    <div>
      {{exampleInput}}
    </div>
  </example>
```

then the div seems to get updated, but there is no message logged to the console. It seems as though the $watch isn't working. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qtWK8HhzOYENul0XGf4k?p=preview).

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered.

Comment: Why do you set 'settings' in the directive's scope? you don't seem to use it at all.

Comment: In this example I don't, but my actual scenario is using the settings. I can update the plunkr to reflect that, but that didn't seem to matter in causing this to happen.

Comment: Ok, no issue, I was just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the example is that you're putting your HTML inside your directive tags. They should be in your template.

This code works

```
   angular.module('inputExample', [])
          .directive('example',
           function() { 
             return{
            scope: {
              'settings': '@'
            },
             restrict: 'E',
             template: '<input data-ng-model="exampleInput" /><div>{{exampleInput}}</div>',
             link: function(scope){
               scope.exampleInput = 1;
               scope.$watch(
                 'exampleInput',
                 function(newTestInput){
                   console.log(newTestInput);
                 },
                 false);
             }
             }
           });
```

With the view as just

```
<example></example>
```

Comment: Excellent. This works in the plunkr. In my real example, I have the template in a separate html file and it still isn't working this way. I'll try to create a plunkr like that and see if I can get it to work. Any idea why having the template in a separate html file would be any different?

Comment: No, it should be the same. Sorry for not providint that in my answer, but am not very practised with plunkr.

Comment: Isn't issue is bcz of "scope" is defined in the directive which ovveride default scope therefore need to define "exampleInput" as well in "scope"?

Comment: @DilipKumar True, if the scope isn't overridden in the `example` directive, then it works. But @peinearydevelopment specified a need for the isolate scope in one of the comments.